# Why same HTTP operation's connections number difference under the same surrouding?

Tags: http, connection, latency

Under the same pc to operation one HTTP operation. 
Lan operation has less connections number than wan's (or add network latency).

Why is it so like as I said? 
What determines how many connections to do this?

Anyone who need to know more detail info pls tell me. 
If need the trace files I will send to him.

Thanks.

Comment: can you please rephrase the question?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the browser is opening extra connections for contained objects.  When you add latency the existing connection is busy when the browser goes looking for an embedded object (scrips, css, images, etc.).  It will then open another connection to fetch the object, speeding up the results.  With no latency, the connection is likely to be idle, so it can be reused.

Comment: Agreed, also how many cached connections are already in the same browser. If the website components are relative or composed of different hostnames to the same webserver, etc.

Answer (score 0):

OK.
I describe my question more detail.

I tested a new published application performance which access via web browser,so the application layer is http.

I watched a strange.
For the same operation,the LAN user open the web have little connections(network layer).
When added some latency(285ms) between LAN user and the web server,there were many tcp connections to complete this operation.

Why the same user had the different numbers for same HTTP operation?